# WINE Keyboard Bug. (Keys are Stuck for a few seconds and then release) (Gaming)

Tags: keyboard, wine, games

So I have an issue with WINE where if I play a game, the Keys time to time get stuck and do not appear to depress in the game. If I hold W for lets say X seconds, it will sometimes stay pressed for 1-4 seconds. Its not a Keyboard problem as I only have this bug in Ubuntu. I have played the exact game in Arch Linux and there were no bugs.

This bug only occurs in WINE and not system-wide/native.

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 x64
Wine Libraries: d3dcompiler_43.dll and d3dx9_43.dll

The Game is Live for Speed 0.6K.

Please Help!

Comment: Perhaps did you use in ArchLinux more recent Wine? Try to use [the latest PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah its fine now. I did use Arch Linux at the time but yeah. Right now using Ubuntu MATE and fairly happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the key repeat. it works for me

[image]